# If using new Rails app BOTH as an API and as a classical MVP app, how is DRY token authentication and versioning of the API accomplished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

With Rails 6.1 I hope to build a new app whose *primary* purpose is to supply a versioned API for a Vue.js front end, and mobile apps, but which also needs the classic Rails MVC views available as a web app (mainly for the group managers, as opposed to individual consumers using the consumer Vue front end).

I know creating a classic MVC Rails app allows the controller to respond_to `json` format, which is ok out of the box for a simple, unversioned  API.

But what is a DRY approach to add the following to the classic MVC Rails app:

- a separate token-based authentication layer for incoming API calls (vs whatever is used for the web app, probably Devise)? No sure where that if-api-use-token-not-devise switch gets handled?
- namespacing/versioning the API, ideally DRY-ly sharing the same namespaced controller between web & API? Or to put it another way, after creating an new Version-2 of the API how does one configure the Rails **web** app to use the Version-2 API (while leaving the V1 API active for for users of older front ends)

Comment: In a previous position, we made lots of apps like that. Our admin area was a rails web app using devise/omniauth. Then we had an api for mobile and react apps where we used doorkeeper

Comment: The concept of versioning doesn't quite apply the same way to a web app. Clients don't usually select a version - you just give everyone the same version.

Comment: In general since the requirements are going to be very different the main thing your web app and API will share is models. And since models are internals they are don't follow the API version. I would use WET instead of DRY and figure out what you can streamline as you go along instead of making really bad abstactions. https://dev.to/wuz/stop-trying-to-be-so-dry-instead-write-everything-twice-wet-5g33